# How to "unlink" bone?

Tags: animation

I've been following along in a tutorial on animation and I must've inadvertently clicked on something because I've animated a part of the model that shouldn't be attached to a bone/armature. (Notice the double rectangles to the upper left of the robot head. These are part of the robot's head, and should remain fixed to the head, but instead they're animated along with the arms).

How do I "unlink" the "head" element(s) in question so that they stay fixed?

Also, I've now just gotten into a state where I can't select anything. The properties area is now all about armatures, and I can't see/recover the "normal" tool icons like "wrench" (for boolean operations, etc.) or "sphere" (for materials, etc.), so I can't do "normal" editing operations.

Here is the file on GitHub: https://github.com/DragonForest/first-robot.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you. I tried uploading, but I got an alert box  message "error uploading". The progress bar completed, and the file is only 1.9Mb.

Comment: you need to put the address of this page in the "Enter the URL" field

Comment: I did that, and checked "agree to terms . . . " but still got error

Comment: For now, I've uploaded the file to GitHub <https://github.com/DragonForest/first-robot> and will upload to giantcowfilms once the errors are sorted out. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reasons your head cube is not parented to the neck bone anymore, and is now parented to the hands, you need to go in *Edit* mode, select this part of your mesh, go in the *Properties* panel > *Data* > *Vertex Groups*, in the dropdown menu on the right of the vertex groups list, select *Remove From All Groups* so that this cube is not part of any group anymore and won't be affected by any bone, then select the *Neck* vertex group in the list and press the *Assign* button so that only the *Neck* bone will affect it.

Comment: Thank you! That's fantastic, and it works great now!!

Comment: One quick question: In Object and Pose mode, it seems that one or two edges on the head are missing, but in Edit Mode, those edges are there. Any ideas why those edges "disappear/reappear", and is there a way to fix that situation?

Comment: Pose mode is for armature, not for an object. And I don't see the edges you're talking about, maybe edit your main question and add a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

In Edit Mode, select the Bone and press W

You can switch the bone direction and others

Comment: Thank you, but two problems: 1. I can't select anything now (I'm not sure why), 2. I don't know which bone is controlling the "head" element(s) that I want to "unlink".

Comment: Correction on the problems: 1. When I click on a bone, and then "W", I only get the following menu choices: Subdivide, Switch Direction, Autoname Left/RIght ,Autoname Top/Bottom, Autoname Front/Back, Flip Names, Symmetrize, 2. I don't know which bone is controlling the "head" element(s) that I want to "unlink".